# How to kill a thread before starting it over again

Tags: c#, multithreading

My goal is to create a list of threads in main program, pass them to one class where I want to start each of threads and kill them afterwards. Basically I need to have a list of threads declared in Main and then start&abort them in my class. What happens is that my program crashes because apparently it's trying to Run a thread which is already ran. What should I change in my code to avoid this issue? I tried to abort threads though it did not work.

Ik it's stupid to run and abort threads but I am doing it for a school project and it's one of my profesor's requirements so ya.

```
//main

 class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<HopTruck> listTH = new List<HopTruck>();
            List<BarleyTruck> listTB = new List<BarleyTruck>();
            List<WaterTruck> listTW = new List<WaterTruck>();
            List<Thread> listThreads = new List<Thread>();

            .... ....
        }
    }
```

```
public class SuperVisor : Interface
    {
        private List<WaterTruck> listTW;
        private List<BarleyTruck> listTB;
        public List<HopTruck> listTH;
        public List<Thread> listThreads;

public SuperVisor(List<HopTruck>listath, List<WaterTruck> listatw, List<BarleyTruck> listatb, List<Thread> listafred, ...)
        {
            ...

            ...

            this.listTH = listath;
            this.listTB = listatb;
            this.listThreads = listafred;
            this.listTW = listatw;
        }

someFunction()
{
for(int i = 1; i<=iletrzebaWody;i++)
                             {
                                 listTW.Add(new WaterTruck(warzelnia, 10));


                             }   
                            foreach(WaterTruck elem in listaTW)
                            {
                                 listThreads.Add(new Thread(elem.Drive));   
                            }

                            listTB = new List<BarleyTruck>();
                            for(int i = 1; i<=iletrzebaBarley;i++)
                             {
                                 listTB.Add(new BarleyTruck(warzelnia, 10));
                                 Console.WriteLine("SV dodaje BarleyTruck: "+i);

                             }   
                            foreach(BarleyTruck elem in listaTB)
                            {
                                 listaFredow.Add(new Thread(elem.Run));   
                            }


                            listaTH = new List<HopTruck>();
                            for(int i = 1; i<=iletrzebaHop;i++)
                             {
                                 listaTH.Add(new HopTruck(warzelnia, 10));
                                Console.WriteLine("SV dodaje HopTruck: "+i);

                             }   
                            foreach(HopTruck elem in listaTH)
                            {
                                 listaFredow.Add(new Thread(elem.Run));   
                            }


                        foreach (var thread in listaFredow)
                            {
                                thread.Start();
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: I do not see code where you attempt to Abort() threads?

Comment: Simply you don't, you let threads end naturally, i couldn't imagine any sane professor asking you to abort threads